# java file read reverse order from middle of the document

Tags: java, file-io

I want to find a keyword in a file. After finding keyword, I want to get 50 words before this keyword and 50 words after this keyword.

I wonder if there is a way to read file in reverse order.

Comment: I wonder if you have tried anything!

Comment: There are a lot of ways, try urself first, then post question, if some problem arises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below code.

```
List<String> previousWords = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> nextWords = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean foundKeyWord = false;

Scanner sc2 = null;
try {
    sc2 = new Scanner(new File("translate.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
    boolean b;
    while (b = s2.hasNext()) {
        String s = s2.next();
        if(!foundKeyWord) {
           if(s.equals(findKeyWord)) {
             foundKeyWord = true;
           }
        }
       //Keyword not found then add to the previouswords list
        if(!foundKeyWord) {
           previousWords.add(s);
        } else {
          //already key found now we need to add next 50 words
           if(nextWords.size <= 50) {
               nextWords.add(s);
           } else {
             //if 50 key words are added then break from the loop, if in case if there are less than 50 words in file after keyword then scanner will end.
             break;
           }

        }

    }
}

//Now we need to fix the previous 50 key words in case if keyword is found after 50th word.

  if(previousWords.size > 50){
     previousWords.subList(previousWords.size() - 50, previousWords.size());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would still need to read the file line by line and word by word to find the word you are looking for... what you could do is to have a buffer which holds 50 words, like a String array and then, load your text, if it is not the word you are looking for, throw it in the buffer, with the new words overwriting the oldest ones. If you find what you need, get all the words from your buffer and read the next 50.

Comment: I think it is ok.But this operation might be slow.Because while reading every word always buffer array must be updated.